# AWS Python Layer Run Locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, layer

How does one run locally a AWS Lambda Function with layers?

My environment:

- Pycharm project for an AWS Lambda Function with Python 3.6 runtime.
- AWS Toolkit
- similar file/folder structure to create a Lambda Layer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-aws-lambda-and-lambda-layers-in-aws-sam/ as follows:

```
    +---.aws-sam
        ....
    +---test
    |       app.py
    |       requirements.txt
    |       
    +---dependencies
    |   \---python
    |           constants.py
    |           requirements.txt
    |           sql.py
    |           utils.py
```

- and deployment template like:

```
testFunc:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: teest/
      Handler: app.test
      Runtime: python3.6
      FunctionName: testFunc
      Events:
        test:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test
            Method: ANY
      Layers:
        - !Ref TempConversionDepLayer

  TempConversionDepLayer:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
        Properties:
            LayerName: Layer1
            Description: Dependencies
            ContentUri: dependencies/
            CompatibleRuntimes:
              - python3.6
              - python3.7
            LicenseInfo: 'MIT'
            RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

I can deploy the function correctly and running it on AWS works well,
whenever i try to run the function locally, it fails with the error message:

```
`Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'sql'`
```

I've tried to read all possible resources about Layers and Pycharm but nothing really helped.

Can anybody give a hand please?

Thank you,

Comment: What does the `import` statement in `app.py` look like?

Comment: @PeterHalverson, i have for example: 
from utils import *
utils being the dependencies/python/utils.py which gets expanded in AWS under /opt, and correctly imported.
The error is : <<Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'utils'>>
(yesterday i had a similar import but from the sql.py file, i was hoping to.)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around this issue in PyCharm by adding a symbolic link to another directory which contained code for the layer

Comment: I'm trying this with pyodbc and have symlinked it, but am still having the issue. I symlinked <project_folder>/pyodbc to the /path/to/extracted/layer_archive

I now import something called pyodbc, but it does not have any of the methods expected.